# Compiling problems gtk+

Tags: c++, c, gtk

After I installed gtkmm I cannot longer run gtk+ for my c-apps.

I get these compiler errors

```
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgtk-3
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdk-3
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This error tells you that the linker is unable to find the specified libraries within its search paths. In addition to the -L command-line option, GCC uses the LIBRARY_PATH environmental variable to find library files, which needs to be written with semi-colon separation on Windows, and colon separation on Unix-like systems.

While I can't tell how the files dropped out of the search path on your system, here are some hints that may help you find their location for yourself: On Unix-style development environmnets, library files are typically located within a 'lib' directory and prefixed with 'lib' in its filename. The extension depends on what kind of library it is (static, shared) and what operating system. When a '-lgtk-3' option is passed to gcc, it may for instance find a 'libgtk-3.so' shared library file on Linux.

Comment: thanks - my OS is windows. The system enviromental variable is c:\gtk3\bin. I think thats correct?

Comment: I checked the All-in-one GTK+ bundle and I see that the 'bin' directory does have quite a few 'lib*' files there, presumably for the convenience of running the binaries in it (can't check on my current system), but it still doesn't have libgtk* files, which are located within the 'lib' directory of the bundle.